# How can I prevent an XSS injection in my website?

Tags: php, mysql, xss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

I know that in a lot of website, if you enter :
 `<script>alert("xss");</script>`
The website will display an error.
Exemple : [http://www.igossips.com](http://igossips.com)

Enter the preceding code in the search box.
The website displays a lot of the code.

How can I prevent this to happen on my own website ??

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1996122/259457

Comment: Please see the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good overview on XSS prevention:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but [you can make it better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) by including a summary or relevant portions of the pages you're linking to. This will also help your answer remain great even if the links you included break in the future.